# My mouse button is malfunctioning, where it usually acts as a double-click when I click once

Tags: mouse, hardware, doubleclick

I know I can set the mouse to have a bottom limit on how fast it should be to double click something, but can I have an upper limit instead, i.e. the double-click should happen slower?

Comment: A dirty micro-switch could lead to the problem, try another mouse first or try the mouse on another computer to check if the problem persists.